# Jenkins pipeline - sh - git push fails randomly - ERROR: script returned exit code 128

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, sh

Environment:
ENV Jenkins Operator
Jenkins 2.249.1
Pipeline

**FAILURE**

```
 [master cc6be50] New customer test60     
1 file changed, 32 insertions     
create mode 100644 deployment/test60.yaml
 + git push origin
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // podTemplate
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 128     
Finished: FAILURE
```

**SAME CODE SUCCESSFUL RUN:**

```
+ git commit -m New customer test49
 [master 9c0b093] New customer test49
 1 file changed, 32 insertions
 create mode 100644 deployment/test49.yaml     
+ git push origin
 To https://github.com/****/xxxxxxxxx.git 770e517..9c0b093 master -> master
```

PLEASE HELP THIS HAS BEEN GOING ON FOR SOMETIME NOW, I AM NOT ABLE TO FIGURE OUT WHAT IS THE ISSUE.

1. I am storing credentials from Jenkins to checkout code.
2. Using sh within stage ''' multi commands 
   '''
    3. This used to work in  older version of Jenkins, recently jenkins operator got restarted and pulled recent version of Jenkins 2.249.1
3. I am mostly seeing the issue with "git push" or in "git" related cmds

FAILURE ON "git ls-remote".

```
+ git ls-remote --heads origin test47     [Pipeline] }[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // podTemplate
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 128
 Finished: FAILURE
```

My earlier working code was based on create new branch and pushing to repo which has random failures so changed the logic to directly push to master.

```
Another failure while deleting the remote branch

Branch name test58 already exists, deleting it
+ git push -d origin test58
[Pipeline] }[Pipeline] // stage[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // podTemplate[Pipeline]
End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 128
Finished: FAILURE
```

CMD FAILED

```
+ git ls-remote --heads origin test81
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // podTemplate
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 128
Finished: FAILURE
```

SAME CMD SUCCESS

```
wc=$(git ls-remote --heads origin $BR |wc |awk '{print$1}')
+ git ls-remote --heads origin test81 
75dfaff2153dec5730066e716c37ad67a46d733a refs/heads/test81 
+ git ls-remote --heads origin test81 
+ wc + awk {print$1} 
+ wc=1 
+ echo Value of wc is $wc Value of wc is $wc 
+ [ 1 -ne 0 ] 
+ echo Branch name test81 already exists, deleting it Branch name test81 already exists, deleting it 
+ git config push.default simple 
+ git push -d origin test81 
To https://github.com/****/svc_workflowexecutor.git 
- [deleted] test81
```

RANDOM FAILURES.

The issues happens randomly in different places (there are about 10 different repos I push to), we are also seeing API rate limit exceeded issue.

Still the issue not resolved, will keep you updated.

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed this behavior and switched to ssh repo urls. I use https when I don't need to make changes

Comment: We are using Jenkins-operator which is creating the slave jenkins POD on the fly and runs the jobs and deletes the POD. I am not sure whether ssh can be setup in this slave POD getting created on the fly. Is your Jenkins (master/slave) directly installed?

[Pipeline] node
Created Pod: jenkins/create-repo-files-94-r5swp-vxw2g-fn7kc
Still waiting to schedule task
‘create-repo-files-94-r5swp-vxw2g-fn7kc’ is offline

Thanks

Comment: another workaround - move creds to the repo remote definition: ```https://username:password@github.com/mtuktarov/myrepo.git```